# Hibernate FetchType LAZY has no impact for unidirectional @ManyToOne

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using SpringBoot (v2.0) JPA with hibernate (v5.4). I have 3 entity classes LaunchGrossSalesBasis, which is connected to LaunchModel & LaunchVersionModel.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class LaunchGrossSalesBasis {
 ...

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "launch_id")
 private LaunchModel launchModel;


 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "version_id")
 private LaunchModelVersion launchModelVersion;

 ...
} 

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LaunchModel {
 ...
 Integer id;

 // Unidirectional - so no mapping in this class
     ...
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LaunchVersionModel {
 ...
 Integer id;

 // Unidirectional - so no mapping in this class
 ...
}


public interface LaunchGrossSalesBasisRepository extends BaseCrudRepository<LaunchGrossSalesBasis, Integer> {

 //working but no effect 
 //@Query("SELECT l FROM LaunchGrossSalesBasis l INNER JOIN l.launchModelVersion v INNER JOIN l.launchModel m WHERE v.id = ?1 AND m.id=?2")  
@Query(value="select * from launch_gross_sales_basis s inner join launch_model m ON s.launch_id = m.id INNER JOIN launch_model_version v ON s.version_id = v.id where s.version_id =?1 and s.launch_id=?2 ", nativeQuery = true)
LaunchGrossSalesBasis findByVersionIdAndLaunchId(Integer versionId, Integer launchId);


... 

}
```

When I call findByVersionIdAndLaunchId(versionId,launchId) from my service layer, I expect only 1 single query, but I always get 3 queries.

```
Hibernate: select * from launch_gross_sales_basis s inner join launch_model m ON s.launch_id = m.id INNER JOIN launch_model_version v ON s.version_id = v.id where s.version_id =? and s.launch_id=? 
Hibernate: select launchmode0_.id as id1_52_0_, ... from launch_model launchmode0_ where launchmode0_.id=?
Hibernate: select launchmode0_.id as id1_57_0_, ... from launch_model_version launchmode0_ where launchmode0_.id=?
```

I tried many different ways (including native), but I always get 3 queries. What am I missing? Like this, I have many more queries, and hibernate is firing 200+ queries for one single complex function.

Any clue will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think problem in native query* but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These additional requests are obviously from the entity's lazy fields. You are mentioning them in the request but Hibernate still loads them lazily. If you want to load them in the request - add `fetch` to your joins.

If you don't use lazy fields but are wondering why Hibernate is loading them - I suppose the answer is because of Lombok's `@Data` annotation. It creates equals/hashcode methods that use the fields. Try to replace it with `@Getter` + `@Setter`. More info about that case you can find in [this article](https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/).

Comment: Yes, You are right. This is because of Lombak @Data annotation. Accepted the answer and also awarded the bounty. Thank you so much.